# Generating and appending data only if the same div doesn't exist

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json

I'm trying to create a dummy application wherein the data will be displayed here based on some selection.

I click on the button "Open Modal" and select some data using the checkbox in the table for a row selection.

The table with populated JSONData would somehow look like :

[image]

```
function showData(){
                var count = 0;
                $('input[name="selectData"]:checked').map(function() {
                    var JSONData =  JSON.parse(decodeURIComponent(this.value));
                    content += '<div class="container parent" id="parent-'+count'"><div class="row article-row"><div class="col-md-6 article data-col"><div class="row"><form class="form-horizontal"><div class="form-group"><label class="control-label col-md-4">Count:</label><div class="col-md-8 article-data">'+JSONData.name+'</div></div></form></div></div><div class="col-md-6 article btn-col"><div class="row del-btn"><button class="btn btn-danger remove-btn">Delete &nbsp;<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span></button></div><div class="row updown-btn"><div class="btn-group"><button class="btn btn-primary btn-sm top-btn"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-up"></span></button><button class="btn btn-primary btn-sm down-btn"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-down"></span></button></div></div></div></div></div>';
                    count++;
                });
                if($('#parent-'+count).length==0) {
                    $('.box').html(content);
                    resetEvents();
                } else {
                    alert("Data already exists!");
                }

        }
```

So, now I select a row using the checkbox from the table, and click on the 'Save' button which would then append the data to a static div with class="box".

However, if a particular div with an id (which I'm generating randomly for the div using: id="parent"+count" as shown in the function above) already exists inside div with class box, it shouldn't add that.

1. Select A & C from the table shown in the screenshot and click on 'Save'.
2. A & C get appended to "div.box" with ids "parent-0" and "parent-1" respectively.
3. Now, select A & B from the table.

Current situation: Nothing is added, and alert is shown as "Data already exists!"

Ideal behaviour: B should get appended to "div.box" with id "parent-2" and alert should be shown as "A already exists!".

How do I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you mean to do something like:

```
 if($('#parent-'+count).length { // this means id exists
       alert("Data already exists!");
 } else {
       $('.box').html(content);
       resetEvents();

 }
```

Comment: your going to have to set a breakpoint before the code sets the new html and then go in the debugging tools and manually search for that id, i'm guessing it already exists and you just don't realize it

Comment: No, it doesn't exist. Also, I've an option to delete a "div#parent-'+count'". It removes the div from the DOM. But, I should be able to add it again.

Comment: you have to set a breakpoint, *IT DOES* exist , i believe that you just are checking for the incorrect value of `count`